# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined in vite/sveltekit with Torus

Tags: node.js, svelte, vite, sveltekit

I need a way to alias Buffer for the browser.

Not sure which module requires this but its probably crypto related.

```
500

Buffer is not defined

@http://localhost:3000/_app/pages/index.svelte-2478ade3.js:1:111754
```

Problem is using Torus node library.

Here is a repo: https://github.com/ralyodio/torus-bufer

```
npm i
npm run build
npm run preview
```

...you will see error. `npm run dev` works fine since node handles requests. Its the browser only environment that is the issue.

The polyfill in `svelte.config.js` appears to not work: https://github.com/ralyodio/torus-bufer/blob/master/svelte.config.js

Update: so it appears the bigger issue is that NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin is not respected when doing npm run build with sveltekit static adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding a vite alias to the es5 version of toruslabs openlogin sdk:

```
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '@toruslabs/openlogin': path.resolve(
                        './node_modules/@toruslabs/openlogin/dist/openlogin.umd.min.js'
                    )
                }
            }
```

I no longer get the "Buffer is undefined" error on static builds.

Comment: so it appears the bigger issue is that `NodeGlobalsPolyfillPlugin` is not respected when doing `npm run build` with sveltekit static adapter.

Answer (score 5):

I had to make changes in 3 files ,
in vite.config.ts , index.html and adding packages

**1.Install Packages**

```
yarn install process util buffer events
yarn add @esbuild-plugins/node-modules-polyfill
```

**2.Update vite.config**

```
import GlobalPolyFill from "@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill";
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import { resolve } from "path";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [svelte()],
    optimizeDeps: {
        esbuildOptions: {
            define: {
                global: "globalThis",
            },
            plugins: [
                GlobalPolyFill({
                    process: true,
                    buffer: true,
                }),
            ],
        },
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            process: "process/browser",
            stream: "stream-browserify",
            zlib: "browserify-zlib",
            util: "util",
        },
    },
});
```

**3.Update index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/src/assets/images/favicon.svg" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Vite App</title>
  <script>
    window.global = window;
  </script>
  <script type="module">
    import process from "process";
    import EventEmitter from "events";
    import {Buffer} from "buffer";
    window.Buffer = Buffer;
    window.process = process;
    window.EventEmitter = EventEmitter;
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="module" src="./src/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```