# I tried to import ccxt into my svelte kit app and got ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined even though I'd only imported it

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, ccxt

I have a minimal reproducible example here about this issue. The issue is that `import ccxt from "ccxt"` gives this error

```
ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined
    at node_modules/ccxt/js/static_dependencies/node-rsa/schemes/pkcs1.js (pkcs1.js:10:10)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=d0062138:3:50)
    at node_modules/ccxt/js/static_dependencies/node-rsa/schemes/schemes.js (schemes.js:2:12)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=d0062138:3:50)
    at node_modules/ccxt/js/static_dependencies/node-rsa/libs/rsa.js (rsa.js:12:15)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=d0062138:3:50)
    at node_modules/ccxt/js/static_dependencies/node-rsa/NodeRSA.js (NodeRSA.js:8:11)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=d0062138:3:50)
    at node_modules/ccxt/js/base/functions/crypto.js (crypto.js:8:17)
    at __require (chunk-RSJERJUL.js?v=d0062138:3:50)
```

steps to reproduce:

1. use the [create a project steps](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/creating-a-project)
2. `npm install ccxt`
3. in the `/src/routes/+page.svelte` use `import ccxt from "ccxt"`

My expected behavior is that the package imports and I can do like [what the docs say to do](https://github.com/ccxt/ccxt)

```
var ccxt = require ('ccxt')

console.log (ccxt.exchanges) // print all available exchanges
```

i saw [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69369543/require-is-not-defined-sveltekit-with-typescript) say basically "to get `require` to work, try adding it as a dev dependency" so i did that:

`npm install --save-dev ccxt`

require still fails. and anyway I don't want to use require, I want to use "import".

edit:

I managed to use [Uncaught ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14202) to make my vite.config.js do this

```
import path from 'path'
import inject from '@rollup/plugin-inject'

import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
        }
    },
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            plugins: [inject({ Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'] })],
        },
    },
})
```

and now i can `console.log(ccxt.exchanges)` server side, but client side it still errors. but, progress.

edit2: I also tried the ticked answer to [ReferenceError: Buffer is not defined in vite/sveltekit with Torus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72267731/uncaught-in-promise-referenceerror-buffer-is-not-defined-in-vite-sveltekit-wi) which says

```
resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '@toruslabs/openlogin': path.resolve(
                        './node_modules/@toruslabs/openlogin/dist/openlogin.umd.min.js'
                    )
                }
            }
```

but this fails as well.

I tried the answer by "Goutham J.M" with many upvotes that was long and complex, and got stuck with error `[ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@esbuild-plugins/node-globals-polyfill'` but I don't know how to solve that and it's too much of a rabbit hole.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, nodejs libraries (as opposed to browser or client-side libraries) like `ccxt` are [not officially supported in client-side SvelteKit](https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8307); they are only supported in server-side SvelteKit.

**Generally, the best solution is to limit usage of nodejs libraries to server-side SvelteKit.** This should be sufficient 99% of the time:

- Call the nodejs library from [+page.server.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#page-page-server-js) and return values from the load function. The values can be accessed from +page.svelte via the `data` prop.
- OR call the nodejs library from an API endpoint in [+server.js](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server). Then `fetch()` the appropriate internal API endpoint URL from +page.svelte (or almost anywhere else).

For the 1% of the time this is not sufficient, you will have to either polyfill nodejs built-in dependencies (`Buffer`) and/or remove nodejs dependencies from the library (`ccxt`) in question.

---

Sometimes polyfilling will get some nodejs libraries to work client-side. (Buffer is a nodejs built-in module):

1. [To fix local dev errors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72773693/117030).
2. [To fix build-time errors](https://medium.com/@ftaioli/using-node-js-builtin-modules-with-vite-6194737c2cd2).

However, it seems you have already tried polyfilling.