# How to use a node module in a browser with Sveltekit?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, svelte, browserify, sveltekit

I am learning javascript and svelte and I have found a [module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/number-to-words) that I want to use. The issue is that the module is built for node, so I can't directly use it on client side with `require('number-to-words')` .

I've installed the package nonetheless and I tried importing it with

```js
import { toOrdinalWord } from 'number-to-words'
```

with no success.

I was looking at solutions like browserify and requirejs but they seem a bit too complicated/convoluted for the simple library I am trying to use and I'm confused as to how to use them with Svelte(kit) specifically.

What should I do to somehow make a call to that library on client-side?

Answer (score 0):

The browser has built-in helper utilities for handling these conversions. Have a look at MDNs docs to see if you find what you need in the Intl API. Notably, when it comes to handling ordinal numbers check the link below.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/PluralRules/PluralRules

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script lang="ts">
    import * as n2w from 'number-to-words';
</script>

{n2w.toWordsOrdinal(21)}
```

You can import it this way, and it works.

Check demo [SvelteKit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-c8gpwx) and for [Svelte](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-li51ty)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you should avoid using node modules in the browser. The SvelteKit way of avoiding node modules on the client-side is to do the computations requiring node modules on the server (either in the [load](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) function or an [internal API route](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/routing#server)), then send the results to the client. This is possible 99% of the time.

More info:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/75550951/117030
- https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/issues/8307